# Removed app is still available - how to remove it?

Tags: applications

I just removed Calibre app via Finder `Cmd+Backspace`. The app cannot be found via F4 key now. But it is still available via context menu "open with", even two versions there. So how app can be *really* removed?

macos 10.12.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trashing an app manually, then you have to delete it's supporting files. Those could be in Application Support, Contextual Menu Items, Preferences, Receipts etc folders.

Use apps like [AppZapper](https://www.appzapper.com/) to uninstall apps completely with all the related files. It's a paid app, but it works very well.

Comment: I might add here that Spotlight is likely finding your Time Machine backup versions of that app. You can exclude your Time Machine drive from Spotlight in spotlight preferences under the privacy tab.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all entries in Finders "Open with" for apps that no longer exist, open Terminal and enter

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

This takes a little while. Then enter

```
killall Finder
```

After that, the invalid entries have been removed from the "open with" menu in Finder. This should work with in macOS versions.

Note that the menu list needs to be rebuilt, so there might occur a slight delay when using it at first.

Unfortunately, the "open with" entries in Finder are often left long after having deleted the app that is listed there. I think that's a bug in macOS.